# I Need Assistance with a MIN Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset that returns multiple rows of data for a customer on the same date of service. I want to only return the row with the lowest TX_ID. I have been trying to use the MIN() function in a subquery to get this result but my query returns no data. Here is the sample of what I am looking to do

| TX_ID | CUSTOMER_ID | SERVICE_DATE | SERV_TECH_ID | TOTAL_CHG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 901772 | 12345 | 3/6/23 | 1125 | 250 |
| 901773 | 12345 | 3/6/23 | 1125 | 75 |
| 901774 | 12345 | 3/6/23 | 1125 | 50 |

[Image of Current Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOgao.png)

[Image of Desired Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wBK6.png)

Desired result

| TX_ID | CUSTOMER_ID | SERVICE_DATE | SERV_TECH_ID | POS_ID |  | LOC_ID REV_CODE | TOTAL_CHG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 901772 | 12345 | 3/6/23 | 1125 | 3081 | 100 | 4425 | 250 |

This is the query I am using but as I said it is not returning any results:

```
SELECT TX_ID
    ,at.CUSTOMER_ID
    ,at.SERVICE_DATE
    ,SERV_TECH_ID
    ,TOTAL _CHG

FROM ARPB_TRANSACTIONS at
    INNER JOIN (
            SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, MIN(TX_ID) AS TX, SERVICE_DATE
            FROM ARPB_TRANSACTIONS
            GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID, SERVICE_DATE
            ) oq
            ON at.CUSTOMER_ID = oq.CUSTOMER_ID AND TX_ID = oq.TX

WHERE at.CUSTOMER_ID = '12345' AND at.SERVICE_DATE = '3/6/23' AND SERV_TECH_ID = '1125' AND VOID_DATE IS NULL

GROUP BY at.CUSTOMER_ID
    ,at.TX_ID
    ,at.SERVICE_DATE
    ,SERV_TECH_ID
    ,TOTAL_TOTAL
```

Comment: As explained in the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which you should have read, please do not post [pictures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data.

Comment: Sample data, images and SQL have no relation.

Comment: The subquery does not use a where clause, outer query has it, so subquery may or may not match the "outer" records. May I suggest using window functions instead?

Comment: Your desired results don't seem to have much to do with your query.  There are 3 or 4 column in your result that aren't referenced anywhere in your query.  I'd suggest maybe deleting this question and make a new one, and be a little clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT at.TX_ID
    ,at.CUSTOMER_ID
    ,at.SERVICE_DATE
    ,at.SERV_TECH_ID
    ,at.TOTAL _CHG
FROM ARPB_TRANSACTIONS at
    INNER JOIN (
            SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, MIN(TX_ID) AS TX
            FROM ARPB_TRANSACTIONS
    WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = '12345' 
AND SERVICE_DATE = '20230623' 
AND SERV_TECH_ID = '1125' 
AND VOID_DATE IS NULL
            GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID
            ) oq
            ON at.CUSTOMER_ID = oq.CUSTOMER_ID AND at.TX_ID = oq.TX
```

Comment: Thank you Cetin for your reply. I moved the Where clause into my subquery and the query works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a small error in your query.

The alias **TOTAL_TOTAL** in your GROUP BY clause doesn't match the column name **TOTAL_CHG** in the SELECT clause. That could be one reason why your query is not returning any results.